# MediaPlayer plays double sounds on change orientation

Tags: java, android, media-player, orientation

I have a big problem with this app. The problem with it is that when the orientation changes to landscape and then change it to portrait the music twice tracks plays at the same time. But when i start the app on portrait i have no problem with it.

```
package com.phone.sensor;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class sensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{
    public boolean musStatus = false;
    public boolean musDeclare = true;
    public MediaPlayer mp = null;

    Sensor accelerometer;
    SensorManager sm;
    TextView acceleration;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            if(mp != null){
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp = null;
            }
        } else {
            if(mp != null){
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp = null;
            }
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sm=(SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        sm.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        acceleration=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.acceleration);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean("musStatus", musStatus);
        outState.putBoolean("musDeclare", musDeclare);
    }

    public Object onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance() {
        return this.mp;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        acceleration.setText("X: "+event.values[0]+
                "\nY: "+event.values[1]+
                "\nZ: "+event.values[2]);

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        if(y > 8.9) {   
            if(musDeclare == true)
            {
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.alexander);
                musDeclare = false;
            }

            if(musStatus == false)
            {
                mp.start();
                musStatus = true;
            }
        }

        if(y < 5)
        {
            if(musStatus == true)
            {
                mp.stop();
                mp.reset();
                mp = null;
                musStatus = false;
                musDeclare = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try putting this block of code in the `OnPause` method of your class

```
      if(mp != null && mp.IsPlaying()){
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
            mp = null;
        }
    }
```